# Linq.Where(x=>x==1) - What Is The Compiler Doing

Tags: c#, linq

I know Linq is defferedexecution but I want to understand what the compiler does with a statement like this and how it works under the hood

I find Linq fascinating but I worry that I dont understand what is happening under the hood

Comment: see https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/09/03/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-2-quot-where-quot.aspx

Comment: The compiler is doing all kinds of crazy things. It's doing method type inference and lambda conversion analysis and local variable capture analysis and expression tree lowering and a whole lot more. I could easily spend a couple of hours explaining each of them. Can you make your question much more specific?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Where() is an extension method that could be implemented as something like this:

```
IEnumerable<T> Where(self IEnumerable<T> sequence, Func<T, bool> predicate) 
{
    foreach(T current in sequence)
        if( predicate(current) )
            yield return current;
}
```

x => x == 1 is an anonymous procedure that returns true if x == 1 and false otherwise, something like so:

```
bool predicate(T value)
{
    return value == 1;
}
```

For the details of how the iterator block in Where() compiles, there's a great series explaining how they are compiled starting [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/07/09/iterator-blocks-part-one.aspx) on Eric Lippert's blog.

Answer (score 2):

It's filtering the query to values which are equal to 1.  Consider

```
IEnumerable<int> values = ...;
IEnumerable<int> filteredValues = values.Where(x => x == 1);
```

Another way to write this would be the following

```
public static IEnumerable<int> ExampleWhere(IEnumerable<int> values) {
  foreach (var x in values) {
    if (x == 1) {
      yield return 1;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it still true that VB .NET lacks the `yield` operator?

Comment: @Yuck yes that is true wit the current version of VB.net

Comment: Look at the upcoming Asynch stuff though - brings Yield to VB, and vast improvements to asynchronous coding to both languages

Answer (score 2):

It kind of depends upon what the underlying collection is. It can make a huge difference if you're talking about LINQ to SQL, LINQ to Entities, or LINQ in general. If this is just a statement on a `List` for instance, it's basically shorthand for the `foreach` enumerator where only items matching the condition are returned in the resulting enumeration.

Answer (score 2):

It is doing this:

```
IQueryable<int> seq = ...;
return Queryable.Where(seq, Expression.Lambda(Expression.Equals(Expression.Constant(1), Expression.Parameter("x"))));
```

This is only slightly simplified.

Edit: I should qualify that I am talking about the case that seq is an IQueryable. The specifiy linq provider does not matter in this case.